# Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular.js and was trying to create a link that displays a form when clicked on, but it doesn't seem to work.

**this my index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div>
              <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">
              <input type="text" ng-model="login.password">
              <button type="button" ng-click="">Login</button>
              <a ui-sref="signUp">Create An Account</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div ui-view></div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**This is the form- signup.html***(registration form and takes only email and password)*

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
          Email Address
          <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          Password
          <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.password" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button ng-click="createUser()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**and this is the controller-app.js**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);

    MyApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
          .state('signUp', {
            url: "/signup",
            templateUrl: "signup.html",
          })
      }
    ]);

<!-- end snippet -->
```

the idea is to display the form after the user clicks the 'Create An Account', the ui-router doesnt seem to work even when trying to load any state, could there be anything i am missing or should change or remove?

please and thank you.

Comment: From what you posted, nothing looks blatantly incorrect. Can you confirm that the templateURL path in $stateProvider is correct? Right now, I would expect signup.html to be in the same directory as your controller-app.js.

Comment: your code is correct maybe need to check file in same directory you call app.js

Comment: Yes the files are all in the same directory...

I am not running it withing wamp nor xampp, would that cause it not to work?

Comment: Check your console to see if there are any errors. And is `createUser()` defined anywhere ?

Comment: Hey Mr bones, i planned on defining createUser() within a different controller once i got the route working, And no no errors in the console.